# Integrative Complexity and Intelligence

Tags: intelligence, bias

In this paper a leading researcher on [Integrative Complexity](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331641271_Integrative_Complexity) suggests that it's only weakly connected to intelligence. Is this disputed in any papers? A friend with Master's in Neurophilosophy is highly skeptical of this contention. I'm having trouble finding references that address the matter at all, apart from those referenced by the paper above.

I'm a layman myself. I'd think working memory varies positively with intelligence and considering more than one perspective takes more memory than considering multiple perspectives. By this naive analysis I'm inclined to agree with my friend. It seems that the research I can find says otherwise.

Put another way, is the capacity for recognizing and mitigating one's biases dependent on intelligence?